# How do I test if a letter is in a list?

Tags: string, rust

I need to test if a character is in a list of character in the most efficient way. I understand that it can be done through a `for` loop, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
fn main() {
    let letra = 'a';
    let vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    // compare: if letra is in vocales {}
}
```

Comment: You may also take a look at [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html). For small sets, a slice may be more efficient, but if it grows in size, a set should be used.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm going to read the Hashset documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vocales.contains(&letra)`, which will be true if the array `vocales` contains the element `letra`:

```
fn main() {
    let letra = 'a';
    let vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

    if vocales.contains(&letra) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is the same algorithm as using a `for` loop; it is not more efficient.